# How does summation over time samples influences DFT?

Tags: discrete-signals, dft

In case of DFT where we have following
$$
Y_{k}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}y_ne^{-j{\frac{2\pi nk}{N}}}
$$

- What happens in case when we change summation, e.g., increase or decrease number of $n$ that we are summation over?
- How does the rest of equation change?
  For example if we decide to sum over $NM$ (if $M<1$ we have windowing and if $M>1$ we have zero padding so I do not assume adding any new info data just scaling the duration of the signal) samples would we rewrite the latter equation like this
  \begin{equation}
  Y_{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{MN-1}y_ne^{-j{\frac{2\pi nk}{MN}}}\tag{1}
  \end{equation}
  or this
  \begin{equation}
  Y_{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{MN-1}y_ne^{-j{\frac{2\pi nk}{N}}}\quad \tag{2}
  \end{equation}
- And what is the explanation behind. Also what is the appropriate scaling when summation limits change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the length of your data is $NM$ long (regardless of $N$), your DFT should be $NM$ long, so the correct equation is (1).

The explanation is simple: how long is your data? Use that length for the DFT.

You may want to define:
$$
y'_n = \left \{ \begin{array}{cl}
y_n, &  0 \le n \le N-1\\
0, &  n \ge N\\
\end{array}
\right .
$$
and operate on that because $y_n$ for $n\ge N$ is not defined.

Comment: And what is then approporiate scaling-$\frac{1}{MN}$ or $\frac{1}{N}$? For example if I  zeropadd my signal would I scale then over all samples (where part of them are essentially zero),i.e.,$\frac{1}{MN}$  or just over ones which are actually representing data ,i.e., $\frac{1}{N}$?

Comment: The scalings are a matter of choice. I'd go with $\frac{1}{MN}$, but some forms of the DFT and its inverse prefer $\frac{1}{\sqrt{MN}}$ on both the forward and inverse transforms.

Comment: But if I scale with $\frac{1}{MN}$ that means that amplitude of zeropadded signal would be different compared to original signal? If I am adding zeros why would my amplitude change?

Comment: Actually, some forms of analysis wrap longer data (by summing) around a shorter FFT.  This sharpens some forms of frequency estimation (at the cost of other artifacts).  It's "sort-of" the opposite of zero-padding.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Yes, you can certainly do that. As you suggest, it'll give you something akin to "time-aliasing" but can be useful if the problem supports it.